# What is the use of Id in spring cloud gateway routes?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Spring cloud gateway accepts id in route builder. I am not able to figure it out what is the use of id in route builder.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: my_route
        uri: http://localhost:8081
        predicates:
        - Cookie=mycookie,mycookievalue
      - id: my_route
        uri: http://localhost:8081
        predicates:
        - Cookie=mycookie,mycookievalue1
```

both of the above routes work properly. I am not sure what`s the use of id then? my assumption was id should be unique across routes.

Comment: So if you inspect the actuator endpoint you can see the routes and their id. You can leave it off, it isn't required and will have a uuid generated

Comment: I can see two routes with same id. Yes, not passing a id generate uuid. But I am not able to get what is the use of id? what will be impact of same id?

Comment: It is like bean name. If you enable debug log you can easily trace data flow by id of your components.

Comment: There is no impact if the id is the same.